# UWP - file access to additional files referenced from file picked by user

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I'm writing an application that amongst other things will have to import some files. The user points to the main file with a picker which grants access to that file. However, there are additional files refrenced within the file. How do I gracefully access them?

To illustrate situation better:

- manifest.xml
- media (folder)

  - image1.jpg
  - image2.jpg
  - image3.jpg

User picks manifest.xml which mentions media files. I'd like to programmatically access them.

I realize I could declare *broadFileSystemAccess* capability, but from what I gather, it still wouldn't work in certain locations. For example if imported files were placed in C:. I would also have to explain myself when submitting application.

Embedding additional files is not possible because I have to work with over 20 years old standard which doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the only way to do this without *broadFileSystemAccess* (which is not cure for everything) is to use FolderPicker and ask for folder containing file to be imported. From what I tested, it grants you access to picked folder and all its subfolders and files.

However, this solution is not perfect. FolderPicker is unable to display files in its dialog (just the folders) so you have to know where the file you want to import is beforehand. Then, after folder is picked, you have to test if it really contains file that can be imported and take into consideration, there might be more than one. It means, you'll have to create another dialog of your own which will ask user which file he wants to import. You might even want to do that with one file just to make sure the user knows what he's doing.